# How to use "Having" and "Group By" using subqueries in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Please help to find count in my query. I am getting an error using  "having" and "group by".

I have modified my code like below to find the similar incident count. I am looking to to find the count based on 2 fields (user_id,item_id)

```
SELECT 
    i.usr_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN inc_data.Rep3 = 'y' THEN 1 END) AS RespBreach,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN inc_data.Res3 = 'y' THEN 1 END) AS ResBreach,
    COUNT(DISTINCT i.incident_id) as CallCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN act1.act_type= 'TRAVEL' THEN ISNULL(act1.service_time, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS Travel_Time,
    SUM(CASE WHEN act1.act_type= 'REMOTE' THEN ISNULL(act1.service_time, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS Remote_Time,
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(inc.incident_id) AS similar_inc_count, 
         inc.item_id, inc.cust_id 
     FROM
         incident inc
     GROUP BY 
         inc.usr_id, inc.item_id
     HAVING      
         (COUNT(inc.incident_id) > 1)) AS similar_Call    
FROM 
    incidents AS i
INNER JOIN 
    inc_data ON i.incident_id = inc_data.incident_id
INNER JOIN 
    actions act1 ON i.incident_id = act1.incident_id 
WHERE 
    i.date_logged BETWEEN '2016-08-20' AND '2016-08-23' 
GROUP BY 
    i.usr_id
```

Expected result:

```
| user_id | RespBreach | ResBreach | CallCount | Travel_Time | Remote_Time | Similer_call |
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
|     111 |          1 |         1 |         2 |         140 |          50 |            0 |
|     190 |          1 |         0 |         2 |          75 |          60 |            1 |
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE incidents (incident_id int,date_logged datetime,usr_id int,dept_id int,item_id int, cust_id int)  

insert into incidents values 
('1001',    '8/20/2016',    '190',  '3',    '800',  '10'),
('1002',    '8/21/2016',    '111',  '4',    '810',  '12'),
('1003',    '8/22/2016',    '190',  '3',    '800',  '10'),
('1004',    '8/23/2016',    '111',  '4',    '822',  '12')


Create TABLE actions ( act_id int, act_type varchar(50) ,   incident_id int,    usr_id   int ,date_actioned datetime,   service_time money)

Insert into actions VALUES
('1',   'TRAVEL',   1001,   190,    8/20/2016,  20),
('2',   'ASSIGN',   1001,   2,  8/21/2016,  1),
('3',   'TRAVEL',   1001,   190 ,8/22/2016, 10),
('4',   'REMOTE',   1001,   190,    8/23/2016,  30),
('5',   'TRAVEL',   1002,   111,    8/21/2016,  40),
('6',   'ASSIGN',   1002,   2,  8/22/2016   ,1),
('7',   'REMOTE',   1002,   111,    8/23/2016,  30),
('8',   'TRAVEL',   1002,   111,    8/24/2016,  60),
('9',   'TRAVEL',   1003,   190,    8/22/2016,  45),
('10',  'ASSIGN',   1003,   2,  8/23/2016   ,1),
('11',  'REMOTE',   1003,   190 ,8/23/2016  ,10),
('12',  'REMOTE',   1003,   190 ,8/23/2016  ,20),
('13',  'ASSIGN',   1004,   2   ,8/23/2016  ,1),
('14',  'TRAVEL',   1004,   111,    8/23/2016,  20),
('15',  'TRAVEL',   1004,   111,    8/23/2016,  20),
('16',  'REMOTE',   1004,   111,    8/23/2016,  20)


CREATE TABLE inc_data (incident_id int,Rep1 char(1), Rep2 char(1),  Rep3 char(1),   Res1 char(1),   Res2 char(1),   Res3 char(1))   

insert into inc_data values
(1001,  'y',    'y',    'y',    'y',    'y',    'n'),
(1002,  'n',    'n',    'n',    'n',    'n',    'n'),
(1003,  'y',    'y',    'n',    'n',    'n',    'n'),
(1004,  'y',    'y',    'y',    'y' ,   'y',    'y');
```

Comment: Your query has some syntax problems.  Maybe you could let us know what the query is supposed to do?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you can find my tables here " http://rextester.com/OQPY39298 "

Comment: I looking to to find the count based on 2 fields (user_id,item_id)

Comment: You should include this information in your question.  Stack Overflow is not a pump and dump service.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry for the little info. Noted for future.

Comment: @Salman Your Expected result is wrong according to the demo code you have attached.Both user_id 111 & 190 exists twice. So similar_call value will be 2 in both the cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can't choose multiple statements in your sub query. Also usually we have to make a relation inside the sub query with its parent query.

I assume that you wanted to pull the number of incidents against the users inside the subquery ,if so you have to code like below..

```
    SELECT i.usr_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN inc_data.Rep3 = 'y' THEN 1 END) AS RespBreach,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN inc_data.Res3 = 'y' THEN 1 END) AS ResBreach,
       COUNT(DISTINCT i.incident_id) as CallCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN act1.act_type= 'TRAVEL' THEN ISNULL(act1.service_time, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS Travel_Time,
       SUM(CASE WHEN act1.act_type= 'REMOTE' THEN ISNULL(act1.service_time, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS Remote_Time,
      ISNULL((SELECT     COUNT(inc.incident_id) -1
         FROM incidents inc
         WHERE inc.usr_id=i.usr_id 
           GROUP BY inc.usr_id,inc.item_id
             HAVING COUNT(inc.incident_id) > 1 
             ),0)AS similar_inc_count   
FROM incidents as i
INNER JOIN inc_data ON i.incident_id= inc_data.incident_id
INNER JOIN actions act1 on i.incident_id=act1.incident_id 
WHERE i.date_logged BETWEEN '2016-08-20' AND '2016-08-23' 
GROUP BY i.usr_id
```

Comment: thanks for advice & query. Can i skip this block ,"  COUNT(similer_inc_count)as  similer_inc_count , "

Comment: If i want to use the ISNULL how can use it for similer_call result

Comment: ISNULL((SELECT     COUNT(inc.incident_id)
         from incidents inc
           GROUP BY inc.usr_id, inc.item_id
             HAVING COUNT(inc.incident_id) > 1),0) AS similar_Call

Comment: Just put an outer out covering for that selected field with isnull function..still i don't know what you are actually needs in your subquey.. modify the query as according to your needs..current query will pull all the incidents against the user if the count of incidents greater than 2.

Comment: @Salman There's no column like similer_inc_count  in your code.

Comment: i just updated the column name to 'similar_inc_count'

Comment: @UnnikrishnanR and J19 for the advice.

Comment: ok man.. i am going out.. will come back by 8.30.. let me know if you are still facing problems...i can support you..

Comment: @UnnikrishnanR : I am getting this error now "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. "

Comment: Hi salman, Try with the updated query... I tested it against the given sample data and the output..

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a correlated subquery, rather than a `group by`.  However, there are other improvements for your query:

```
SELECT i.usr_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN id.Rep3 = 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RespBreach,
       MAX(CASE WHEN id.Res3 = 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ResBreach,
       COUNT(DISTINCT i.incident_id) as CallCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.act_type = 'TRAVEL'
                THEN a.service_time
                ELSE 0
           END) AS Travel_Time,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.act_type = 'REMOTE'
                THEN a.service_time
                ELSE 0
           END) AS Remote_Time,    
        (SELECT COUNT(*) AS similar_inc_count
         FROM (SELECT inc.item_id
               FROM incident inc
               WHERE inc.cust_id = i.user_id
               GROUP BY inc.item_id
               HAVING COUNT(inc.incident_id) > 1)
              ) inc
        ) AS similar_Call    
FROM incidents i INNER JOIN
     inc_data id
     ON i.incident_id = id.incident_id INNER JOIN
     actions a 
     ON i.incident_id = a.incident_id 
WHERE i.date_logged BETWEEN '2016-08-20' AND '2016-08-23' 
GROUP BY i.usr_id;
```

Notes:

- The subquery is my best guess as to your intentions.  It counts the number of items for the user that have more than one incident.
- The `COUNT(DISTINCT)` have been replaced with `MAX()`.  The `MAX()` is both more understandable and more efficient.
- The `IFNULL()` has been removed from the `SUM()` to simplify the logic.

Comment: it give me syntax error  : " Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near ')'. "

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT i.usr_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN inc_data.Rep3 = 'y' THEN 1 END) AS RespBreach,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN inc_data.Res3 = 'y' THEN 1 END) AS ResBreach,
       COUNT(DISTINCT i.incident_id) as CallCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN act1.act_type= 'TRAVEL' THEN ISNULL(act1.service_time, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS Travel_Time,
       SUM(CASE WHEN act1.act_type= 'REMOTE' THEN ISNULL(act1.service_time, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS Remote_Time,
        (SELECT COUNT(inc.incident_id)
         FROM incidents inc
         GROUP BY inc.usr_id, inc.item_id
         HAVING COUNT(inc.incident_id) > 1) AS similar_Call    
FROM incidents as i
INNER JOIN inc_data ON i.incident_id= inc_data.incident_id
INNER JOIN actions act1 on i.incident_id=act1.incident_id 
WHERE i.date_logged BETWEEN '2016-08-20' AND '2016-08-23' 
GROUP BY i.usr_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your query, We need to use Where clause as Suggested by Unnikrishnan.